# JavaScript - How do i check execution of my command finished or not?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I want to make a 3D matrix and fill it with values from a text file then make a grid with size 180*90, and color it with respect to values from my matrix,

for example: blue for negative values, red for positive and white for zero values.

I want to store what i read from my text file in a 3D matrix.

but i have problem, when i execute my html file and use
 `console.log(myMatrix)` it shows me `undefined` and when i copy-paste `for-loop` in console,

for example
 `console.log(myMatrix[0][0][4])` shows me correct answer which is `90`.

so i guess maybe the problem is related to **javaScript**, because **js** read all code and when i try `console.log(myMatrix[0][0][4])` it shows me `undefined` because reading file and store in array does not complete but when i use console command because it is in RAM, I can see correct answer.

therefore, i decided to check if reading the file and store it in an array completed, then execute my `for-loop` to store values from an array to `myMatrix`. But i do not know how can i do this?

i tried use `setTimeout` but i thought maybe execution time in my system is different from other system or also network.Also i thought for Callback function but i did not achieved anything. I hope you help me.

this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="grid"></div>
        <script>
        //creat 1670 numbers of matrices with size of 180*90
                var myMatrix = new Array(1670)
                for (var i=0; i<1670; i++){
                    myMatrix[i] = twodmatrix()
                }

                function twodmatrix(){
                    var myMat = new Array(180)
                    for (var i=0; i<180; i++){
                        myMat[i] = new Array(90)
                    }
                    return(myMat)
                } 


                var myGrid = new Array(1670)
                for (var i=0; i<1670; i++){
                    myGrid[i] = twodmatrix()}




                var array = new Array()

                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xmlhttp.open("GET", "tempanomaly_new.txt", true);
                    xmlhttp.send();
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                            parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                        }
                    }
                function parse (text) {
                     array = text.split(",");
                     return array
                    //Do something

                }


                function treeDmatrix(){ 
                var n=0;            
                for(var i=0;i<1670;i++){
                    for(var j=0;j<180;j++){
                        for(var k=0; k<90; k++){myMatrix[i][j][k]= array[n];
                                                n +=1;}}}

                }                           

                /*var mycolor;

                for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
                    if (array[i] == 0){ function white(){  mycolor = d3.scalelinear().domain([1,5]).range(["white"])}}
                    else if (array[i] > 0 ){ function red(){ mycolor = d3.scalelinear().domain([1,5]).range(["red"])}}
                    else if (array[i] < 0 ){function blue(){ mycolor = d3.scalelinear().domain([1,5]).range(["blue"])}}                 
                }       





                /* Start make a grid and color it */
                /*
                const BLOCK_SIZE = 30;
                const BLOCK_SPACE = 5;
                const ROW_SIZE = 90;
                const COL_SIZE = 180;



                gridData = new Array(COL_SIZE);
                for (var i = 0; i < COL_SIZE; i++) {
                    gridData[i] = new Array(ROW_SIZE);
                    for (var j = 0; j < ROW_SIZE; j++) {
                        gridData[i][j] = {
                            x: (i + 1) * BLOCK_SIZE + BLOCK_SPACE,
                            y: (j + 1) * BLOCK_SIZE + BLOCK_SPACE,
                            size: BLOCK_SIZE,
                            }}}


    var grid = d3.select("#grid")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", "100%")
    .attr("height", "100%")
    .style("color", "#b2b2b2");

    var row = grid.selectAll(".row")
    .data(gridData)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "row");

    var column = row.selectAll(".square")
    .data(function(data) { return data; })
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "square")
    .attr("x", function(data) { return data.x; })
    .attr("y", function(data) { return data.y; })
    .attr("width", function(data) { return data.size; })
    .attr("height", function(data) { return data.size; })
    .style("stroke", "#222")
    .style("fill", function(data) { return mycolor(data)});*/
        </script>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: you need to start with functional programming paradigm and break all the request and keeping it asynchronous using promises, callbacks and async await.

Answer (score 1):

The `onreadystatechange` is an asynchronous function and hence it is most likely be called only after running all of your script. So, you have to wait till your `parse` function is called and then go ahead with processing the data. I would suggest you to move all your code inside `parse` and check. Please read about `Promise` if you really want to do it the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

XMLHTTPRequest is asynchronous. This means the JS will just initiate the data request and continue processing the rest of your code. When the requested data arrives (I would say for the simplicity), it fires the `onreadystatechange` function.

Now, this is the moment you should fill your array and start processing it. Put your loop inside a function named `buildMatrix` and execute the function once the data is arrived.

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                            var d = parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                            buildMatrix(d);
                        }
                    }
```

And log the matrix to the console after all these are over. The last line to execute in your code therefore is

```
buildMatrix(d)
console.log(myMatrix)
```